# Apple maps cant locate an address,IOS6

Tags: ios, ios6, apple-maps

Out application is calling Apple maps for finding out an address on map
this is how we are sending address to maps

```
http://maps.apple.com/?q=1858 East Pike Street,(Old Route 50),Clarksburg,WV 26302 (Harry Green Chevrolet)&ll=39.278,-80.299
```

Which says, No data found error!
But the same location is found on Google maps
Can anyone suggest me how the mentioned location can be found on Apple maps
Thanks in advance

Comment: There are spaces in that URL, are you sure the underlying software can cope with that?

Answer (score 0):

First, test if the stand-alone Apple Maps app can actually recognize the address, as entered. If not, play with the stand-alone app until you figure out what confuses the service. Google has hosted their service for a… longer time and they're, well, a search company -- it's only natural that their expertise includes advanced language processing.

On a second note, I would also suggest that you use the new iOS 6 API for opening Maps. This is how I do routing from coordinates.

```
// if you know the coordinates:
MKPlacemark * srcPlacemark = 
    [[[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:src 
                           addressDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionary]] autorelease];
MKMapItem * srcObj = [[[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:srcPlacemark] autorelease];
// alternatively, if you want to use "user's current location":
// MKMapItem * srcObj = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];

// if you know the address:
NSDictionary * dstDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          self.addressLabel.text, kABPersonAddressStreetKey,
                          self.city ? self.city : @"", kABPersonAddressCityKey,
                          self.country ? self.country : @"", kABPersonAddressCountryKey,
                          nil];
MKPlacemark * dstPlacemark = [[[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:dst addressDictionary:dstDict] autorelease];
MKMapItem * dstObj = [[[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:dstPlacemark] autorelease];

return [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:srcObj, dstObj, nil] 
                      launchOptions:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving 
                                                                forKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey]];
```